# bind v-model to the property which does not exist (Array) in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have some questions getting from the database, It has options also. Then rendering those on the webpage.

like This

```
              <div v-for="(question,index) in questions">
                    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main m-b-20">
                             {{ index+1 }}. {{ question.question }}
                    </div>

               <div v-for="(option,index) in question.options" 
                    class="reg__form-radioitem" :key="index">
                 <div>

               <input class="checkbox countable__input" 
                     v-model="question.answer"
                     :value="option.option" 
                     type="checkbox" 
                    :id="question.id+option.id">
               <label :for="question.id+option.id">
                      {{ option.option }}
               </label>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div
```

This is working fine for input type `text` and `radio` but for `checkbox` it does not work. It checks all the checkboxes in that loop.

`question.answer` does not exist on the data.i am trying to add new property `answer` using `v-model` 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to predefine the question.answer, should exist after this:

data: {
    question: {
       answer: null
    }
}

Comment: data is coming from the database. how i can store that as an empty array?

Comment: any other option?

Comment: Add `"" answer` to your SQL select field list.`
e.g. `SELECT field, field, "" answer FROM table`

OR After fetching data from the database, loop through the rows and add `answer` to each row with an empty string.
e.g. assume you are using PHP
`while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      $row->answer = '';
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input class="checkbox countable__input" 
    v-model="question[answer]"
    :value="option.option" 
    type="checkbox" 
    :id="question.id+option.id">
<label :for="question.id+option.id">
      {{ option.option }}
 </label>
```